# Developing Premium Tumblr Themes

Tags: themes, tumblr

I'm interested in developing premium themes for Tumblr. I can find little information on the website about the process - I am assuming after submitting a theme, you are presented with options for price and so forth.

Neither the [developer](http://www.tumblr.com/developers)
or [themes](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/) page has any info.

What is the process / guidelines / rules? Are there any online resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tumblr's [Terms of Service](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms_of_service), under the section titled **Blog Themes** it states:

"To develop and distribute Custom Themes that are Premium Themes, please email us."

Comment: Haha, slick! I bet they get back to you really quickly too!

Answer (score 1):

Don't just submit! That goes to the free section once approved and it's not easy to take down. Always email them first, but they either don't reply or take a very very long time